# Get back access to the development server

Tags: python, django

I ran `manage.py check --deploy¶` for my django project before I was actually ready to deploy and now I can't seem to run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

for any of my projects. Is there anyway to reverse my actions?

This is the error I get in my terminal whenever I try to access a project in my browser.

```
code 400, message Bad request version ('\x9a\x9a\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93êê\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00ÿ\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00')
```

[10/Feb/2022 11:33:40] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access your dev server over https

`manage.py check --deploy` most likely told you to set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in your settings.py

Try reverting it back to `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`

Comment: Thanks for the reccomendation, I tried that and it still gives me the same error

Comment: Perhaps you also changed SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS and you are still being redirected to the https version of your site. There is a big warning about this at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-seconds

Comment: i ended up changing both and also deleting my migrations and my browsing data and it finally worked!

Comment: @JimmyPells Thanks. Setting it to 0 and clearing my browser data fixed it